# In GDB, what is the proper way to call C++ functions inside namespaces or classes in non-debug binaries?

Tags: c++, debugging, namespaces, gdb

GDB's `call` command normally works great for calling functions, as long as the symbols are present. But if the function is in a namespace or a class, suddenly it won't work unless it was compiled with debugging information.

For example, let's say I have this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace ns {
    void test()
    {
        std::cout << "ns::test" << std::endl;
    }
}

struct cl {
    static void test()
    {
        std::cout << "cl::test" << std::endl;
    }
};

void func()
{
    std::cout << "func" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ns::test();
    cl::test();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I saved that as `test.cpp`, compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -o test`, then started it inside GDB:

```
$ gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 11.1
[...]
Reading symbols from test...
(No debugging symbols found in test)
(gdb) start
```

Calling `func` from GDB works as expected:

```
(gdb) call (void)func()
func
```

The others, however, do not:

```
(gdb) call (void)ns::test()
No symbol "ns" in current context.
(gdb) call (void)cl::test()
No symbol "cl" in current context.
```

It works fine if it was compiled with `-ggdb`, but that's not usually an option if the source code is unavailable.

It's worth pointing out that GDB is aware of these functions and their addresses:

```
(gdb) info functions
...
0x0000000000001169  ns::test()
0x000000000000119b  func()
0x000000000000124e  cl::test()
...
(gdb) info symbol 0x1169
ns::test() in section .text
(gdb) break cl::test()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1252
```

Those names will also autocomplete if I press Tab, even in a `call` command, meaning in that case it will autocomplete to something that doesn't work.

In addition, calling those functions works fine if I use their raw names:

```
(gdb) call (void)_ZN2ns4testEv()
ns::test
(gdb) call (void)_ZN2cl4testEv()
cl::test
```

So what's the deal here? Is this a bug in GDB, or is there some kind of special syntax I'm unaware of?

Comment: Try quoting the whole thing so GDB doesn't try to search for the nonexistent `ns` symbol. `call (void)'ns::test'()`. Also, GDB willl use the C calling convention, and that's OK in this case but not generally.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That worked; thanks a lot! Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C++ compiler kindly put `ns::test` into the symbol table. All we need to do is  prevent GDB's expression evaluator from trying to look up the non-existent symbol `ns`. To do this, put the entire function name in single quotes.

```
(gdb) call (void)'ns::test'()
ns::test
```